# SSIS Package string to datetime

Tags: ssis

I have a derived column data flow component and I need to insert data to a table.

I am having a problem converting the following string to DATETIME "20130822 14:52:53", how would I go about this?

Please assist

Comment: You have a derived column that is generating the above string or you are attempting to use a derived column to generate a datetime out of the above string? What expression(s) have you tried and how is not working?

Comment: I set the expression to the above to test it out.
I've tried (DT_DATE)("20130822 14:52:53") and (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)("20130822 14:52:53"), but when I use those they turn red.

Comment: (DT_DATETIME)"27.09.2013 18:22:17"

Answer (score 1):

Derived column code:

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(string),1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(LTRIM(string),5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(LTRIM(string),7,2) + SUBSTRING(LTRIM(string),9,LEN(LTRIM(string)) - 7))
```

Result:

```
string              date
20130822 14:52:53   2013-08-22 14:52:53.000
```